# Why does Prolog predicate member/2 print an extra whitespace in output?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I really don't understand why Prolog prints a single whitespace after the member/2 predicate only. The following is the text from my console.

```
?- member(1, [1, 2, 3]).
true .

?- string("why").
true.
```

This is really driving me crazy!

Comment: In the first case, `true` is a result and a prompt awaiting you to type something to tell Prolog what to do next. I assume the period you show is because you pressed `.`, but you could have pressed `;` or some other valid command it expects. In the second case, it's just a result with no input being requested. It's pretty clear. No need to panic. Just breathe...

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation!
I was writing a parser and I thought this could really mess with characters parsing, but fortunately this is not the case!

Comment: Yes, here you're just dealing with an artifact of the human interaction. The result you are seeing is not literally returned by the predicates when called in a program. They just visually indicate success or failure of the predicate call for the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an intended feature to show that you have actually aborted a query at the toplevel. Let's consider a more explicit case where you initially get:

```
?- member(1,[1,1]).
   true█
```

Here, Prolog confirms that this is true but still awaits your response. If you ask for more with <kbd>SPACE</kbd> or <kbd>;</kbd> you will get the next solution:

```
?- member(1,[1,1]).
   true
;  true.
```

However, if you hit <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>.</kbd>, Prolog will abort your query.  To show this on the screen SWI inserts an extra space:

```
?- member(1,[1,1]).
   true .
```

In Scryer and Trealla this is more explicit:

```
?- member(1,[1,1]).
   true
;  false.
```

Traditionally, many implementations never asked for alternatives upon ground queries — when the query itself did not contain any variable. This "optimization" often hid unexpected loops.

In your example, Prolog did not know whether or not a further answer is possible, so it prompts for the moment. If you then ask for more, you get:

```
?- member(1, [1, 2, 3]).
   true
;  false.
```

which says that there is no further solution.